# An issue with actionbarsherlock fragments and backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, back-stack

I'm trying to learn how to work with fragments, using the actionbarsherlock. I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6uNjVEu7_Q). Everything worked, until the point I tried to create another fragment, which will not be a part of the action bar. A user clicks a button in one of the fragments:
[image]
And that fragment opens:
[image]
I want to click on the back button and to return to the previous fragment. This is how I tried to do it - to add this fragment to the backstack:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.btn1:
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment_Products);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
        break;
    }
}
```

If I click on the back button at this stage - it works, I return to the previous fragment (Catalog). However, if at this point I go to another tab, for example "Social", and hit the back button, this is what I get:
[image]
Two fragments overlapping each other. If I keep on clicking on other tabs - it messes even more (I have a video of it, but it seems I can't embed video here).

This is the code of my Main Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setTitle("Fragments app");

    ActionBar.Tab FragmentSocialTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Social")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.star_on);
    ActionBar.Tab FragmentWebTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Web");
    ActionBar.Tab FragmentCatalogTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Catalog");

    Fragment Fragment_Social = new Fragment_Social();
    Fragment Fragment_Web = new Fragment_Web();
    Fragment Fragment_Catalog = new Fragment_Catalog();

    FragmentSocialTab.setTabListener(new TabsListener(Fragment_Social));
    FragmentWebTab.setTabListener(new TabsListener(Fragment_Web));
    FragmentCatalogTab.setTabListener(new TabsListener(Fragment_Catalog));

    actionBar.addTab(FragmentCatalogTab);
    actionBar.addTab(FragmentWebTab);
    actionBar.addTab(FragmentSocialTab);

    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(2);
}
```

And the code of my Tab Listener:

```
class TabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener{
    public Fragment fragment;

    public TabsListener(Fragment fragment){
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
}
```

Why is it happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: By back button are you referring to to the `R.id.btn1`? You can go backstack via `fragmentManager.popBackStack()` method.

Comment: No, I mean the physical button on the device (or the emulator in this case). `R.id.btn1` should open the new fragment, which isn't part of the action bar tabs.

Comment: I suggest looking over [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabsPager.java) and implementing it with a pager. This way you have  swiping and less of a headache.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this type of thing quite often when converting apps to run as action bar / fragments. You have not hidden / detached the old fragment.

I suggest you do something like this in onTabUnselected

```
        if (mFragment != null) { 
                 ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  

                 ft.hide(mFragment);    //hide old fragment ...
                 ft.detach(mFragment);  //detach 

                 ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();   

        }
```

For further information, I recommend this (it contains sample TabListener code that will help you) :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html